# retain jquery-ui element classes after jquery .load()

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-button

I have a page on which I'm using [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/), what I'm doing is loading the content of each tabs via Ajax, but the problem I'm having is that, in the content of my tabs, the buttons (I'm using [jQuery ui button](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/)) lose all their jquery ui classes, meaning:

When the page loads for the first time, my buttons look like this:

```
<button class="my_button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"></span>
</button>
```

As you can see, my buttons have all the jquery-ui classes `ui-button, ui-widget, etc...`. Also, my buttons have a span which displays a plus(+) sign as a label for my buttons. Therefore, my buttons display correctly.

But when I load the same content (which contains the same buttons) via Ajax, my buttons become like this:

```
<button class="my_button"></button>
```

As you can see, I lose all the jQuery ui classes of my button. Therefore, the button is not styled

How can I fix this?

**NOTE** : Please note that I did not manually add those jquery-ui classes to my buttons in my HTML. When you initialize the buttons using `$(".my_button").button();` in jQuery, jQuery automatically applies all the necessary jquery-ui classes to my button appropriately. So please don't tell me it's because I didn't not assign the jquery-ui classes to my buttons upfront (I should not have to). Also, I tried [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), none of those work.

Please help me with this anyone

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure but once I've faced this problem and solved it using the way I answered it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've faced this problem once and solved this problem using the document.ready call like

```
function myreadyFunc(){
    $(".my_button").button();
    // Other codes
}
```

I had my document.ready like following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    myreadyFunc();
});
```

After each ajax (success) call I used to call

```
myreadyFunc();
```

Hope this will help you too. I used this approach to execute document.ready's code that was not possible by calling document.ready after each ajax call.

Comment: Do you put the `myreadyFunc()` outside of the `$(document).ready()`? Cause I just tried this and it doesn't work

Comment: Yes you should put myreadyFunc() outside the $(document).ready()

Comment: So, in other words, you put all the code contained in your `$(document).ready()` inside `myreadyFunc()`? and call `myreadyFunc()` inside the `$(document).ready()` AND after each Ajax calls?

Comment: Ok, but for me the Ajax calls are in my `$(document).ready()`, so I'm assuming they will now be inside `myreadyFunc()`. So I will have calls to `myreadyFunc()` INSIDE of `myreadyFunc()` after each Ajax calls? Or do you perfom your Ajax inside the `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: If You load some content using ajax and if there is something like button that you want to be visible as ui button then you should call $(".my_button").button() to apply the style and hence this code is in your ready event but you cant trigger it after ajax call so wrap it inside another function and call as many times you want.

Comment: But you can put your ajax call inside your $(document).ready()

Comment: just show me a little Fiddle example instead if you don't mind

Comment: Question, when you say AFTER an Ajax call, do you mean really after the `.load()` or WITHIN the callback of `.load()` cause for some reason I can't get this to work

Comment: Yeah it works!, I was calling my function really AFTER my call to `.load()`, NOT within my callback. Thanks man

Comment: Welcome and really glad to know that and going to delete my fiddles, is that ok ?